# Randomly Selecting A List In Python?

Tags: python

I am making a hangman game in Python, and I understand how to randomly select an item from a list, but I was wondering if there was a way to randomly select the list in general.

For example, I have two lists, list1 and list2
Is there a way to randomly select between list1 and list2, and then randomly select a word from the randomly selected list.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: make a list that contains both other lists and `random.choice()` that list

Comment: it is the same as selecting a random element from a list, only the lists are your elements!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) twice:

```
import random

first = ['one', 'word']
second = ['two', 'more', 'and']

selected = random.choice(random.choice([first, second]))

print(selected)
```

**Output**

```
word
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

# Create a list of your lists
list_of_lists = [lists1, list2, list3]

# Select a random list from your list of lists
random_list = random.choice(list_of_lists)

# Select a random word from the randomly selected list
random_word = random.choice(random_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` to select a random list, and then use `random.choice` again to select a value from that list:

```
import random

list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = ['4','5','6']

word = random.choice(random.choice([list1, list2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The two list case if covered by other answers.

If you have an arbitrarily nested, possibly irregular list (or sequence), you can write a recursive function.

```
from collections import Sequence
import random

def go_deeper(x): 
     return (isinstance(x, Sequence) and not 
             isinstance(x, (str, bytes))) # and other sequence types you wish to exclude                                                                          

def select(candidate): 
     if go_deeper(candidate): 
         return select(random.choice(candidate)) 
     return candidate
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar']                                                                                                 
>>> select(l)                                                                                                          
'bar'
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> l = [[[(0,)]]]                                                                                                        
>>> select(l)                                                                                                          
0
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> l = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5]], [[6, [7, 8]], 9]]                                                                          
>>> select(l)                                                                                                          
9
>>> select(l)                                                                                                          
1
>>> select(l)                                                                                                          
2
```